# xCode If UITableView Cell Contents isEqual

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiview, row

So right now I have the following code:

```
if ([[contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Hydrogen"])
{
Hydrogen *hydrogen = [[Hydrogen alloc] initWithNibName:@"Hydrogen" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:hydrogen animated:YES];
hydrogen release];
}
```

Basically, this code says that if the row that is equal to "Hydrogen" (this is a row in a UITableView), then it will load the XIB called "Hydrogen.xib" However, when I add a search bar to my code, the search works fine, but when I tap into the results the row that is displayed is always the first row in the table. How would I fix this, I think it has something to do with the rows in the code above...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could duplicate your array, but put in the view controllers as strings instead.
Then use:

```
Class detailClass = NSClassFromString([controllersArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);

UIViewController* detailViewController = [[[detailClass alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```